# [slam_toolbox]: Failed to compute odom pose

Tags: slam, odometry, mapping, ros-humble, synchronization

I'm trying to run my simple robot in the Flatland simulator, ROS2 Humble. The problem occurs when I try to execute the command

```
ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py
```

At that moment, I encounter the error

```
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [WARN] [1702066299.830374687] [slam_toolbox]: Failed to compute odom pose.
```

No matter what I do, I can't figure out why this error occurs.

I am also attaching the view_frames, where, I don't see mistake, the inheritance tree seems to be well established and the "Average rate" matches as well:
[image]

Additionally, I am attaching the rqt graph connections:

[image]

I've tried echoing /odom and /scan. The odom shows the exact position of the robot where I have it, and from the LIDAR, I also see the response and it seems to be working correctly.

Any suggestion what could solve my problem?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: screenshot of Rviz. [image]
echoes: [image]

Comment: What other warnings did you see before that from TF2?

Comment: No, only that one related with odom pose. I added one screenshot from Rviz. As you can see, the model is not reloading map topic.

Comment: Hey @SteveMacenski ,I've updated the question to add an image showing the output from the echoes of /scan, /odom, and /tf. I measured the laser and it shows correct values, the same as the odom, because I spawned the robot at (-2,0,0) without moving it for now. Do you have any suggestions on what to check? What do you think is the most likely solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I can see the standard frame in slam_toolbox param file is `base_footprint`. See [yaml-file](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/blob/ros2/config/mapper_params_online_async.yaml).
I can't see it in your tf.